# JS readyState 'interactive' and 'DOMContentLoaded' event

Tags: javascript

Please, look at the following script:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log('initialize');
});
```

If this script is loaded when `document.readyState === 'interactive'` then I'll never see 'initialize' message; but if this script is loaded when `document.readyState === 'loading'`, I'll see 'initialize' message. So, I think that 'interactive' is the same as 'DOMContentLoaded', and I should use the following code in order to see 'interactive' message always:

```
var initializeFn = function() {
  console.log('initialize');
}

if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initializeFn);
}
else {
  initializeFn();
}
```

Is this code correct? If not, please, fix it. Thanks!

Comment: When do you get state as `interactive` ?

Comment: Have you referred [__Document.readyState__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)